# Excel desktop, AzureAD authentication not working

Tags: excel, office-addins, azure-ad-graph-api, excel-addins, exceljs

While developing an Excel Add-in I encountered a problem. It works in the online version without problems, but when it is running on the desktop version, it cannot open any popup window to authenticate the user.

- AzureAD to do the authentication process.
- Front end is react and was generated with the Yeoman generator.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing it the right way, or what should I do to work?

Comment: Please share the documents or API examples you refer to.

Comment: @AllenWu i used https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal for the AzureAD implementation and the use of the yoman followed this guide 
 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator

Comment: We may have hit the same issue. With office release version 1902 our add-in authenticated, but hit an error in a version released shortly after.  The issue remains unresolved https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers/issues/143.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely referring to this issue, which is caused by add-ins changing to use the Edge engine instead of the outdated Internet Explorer engine in Office versions > 1907: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers/issues/143

The official response from Microsoft has amounted to a grand total of nil, as they have repeatedly and consistently shut down the community when this bug has been brought to their attention. We ended up needing to start our own fork of the project.

You can install it with the following two commands:

```sh
# remove the broken Microsoft version
npm uninstall --save @microsoft/office-js-helpers
# install the working version
npm install --save @splashback/office-js-helpers
```